# Some unkown effect is comming in my kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Please See The image
In this animation I have used lines and quad below lines.
I have added both(lines and quad) from one side(from right) and removed it from left side, also i have removed their color's from Instruction Group.
It is coming after I have added Image in background of the animation.
And If I comment the code below it will not come.

```
self.img = Image(source = f'{random.randint(1,2)}.jpg', pos = (0, 0), size = Window.size, allow_stretch = True, keep_ratio = False)
        self.add_widget(self.img)
        self.img.bind(size = self.update_rect,)
```

Please see the code and help me.
[image: Unknown Effect]

Here is the complete code.
I really do not have any idea why its coming like this.
The effect is cool but its not in full that's the problem.
[Code Link](https://github.com/Abhay420000/2D-Path-GEN)

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that is happening, but messing with your code I found that it can be eliminated by modifying your `animate_path()` method to create a new `InstructionGroup` (based on the current one), with the updated positions. Then remove the current `InstructionGroup` and add the new one.

Comment: Its coming after adding I have added an image in background. But i do not know why.

Comment: And their is another way to stop it by hiding it by shifting that part in left side.